# WSUS synchronization stuck and 0%

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, wsus

I, now, have two WSUS servers (one is running on Windows Server 2003 and the other on Windows Server 2008), I am trying to decommission one of them. I followed the [instructions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/508.how-to-move-wsus-from-one-server-to-another.aspx) on how to move WSUS server.  I am trying to sync the two servers via Update Service console, before I decommission it, but it's getting stuck at 0%.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I missing something?  Please, help!

Thanks!

Comment: How long has it been "stuck"?

Comment: We ran it overnight, so at this point 14-16 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had strange things happen when trying to use the file system copy route for this kind of migration. In retrospect I think it was mostly due to file system permissions issues either on the updates or the database. I found it easier to axe the new WSUS instance and start over.

This is the method I use.

1. Install WSUS on new server. Use a local database.
2. During configuration wizard choose "Synchronize from another WSUS server…", and provide your original host.
3. Wait for initial synchronization to complete. In my case this took several hours.
4. Change the new server from a replica to standalone.
5. Install the [WSUS API Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=94784) on both systems.
6. Export settings with "wsusmigrationexport.exe settings.xml"
7. Copy settings.xml to new server
8. Import settings with "wsusmigrationimport.exe settings.xml All None"
9. Cut over your hosts to the new system via group policy. I started
   with a few targeted OUs to test and expanded from there.

Comment: Whether the database is local or not really doesn't impact it much, other than it could possibly be one less thing to worry about. [SQL permissions are fairly straightforward for WSUS.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708595%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @nojak - I think the issue I ran into was the NTFS permissions from attempting to copy the database from server to server, not within SQL itself. :)

Comment: I was just putting that comment on there for people that read it in the future, so that they don't think they have to use a local db. I figured you had your reasons for doing so.